# Running Microsoft Office VBA macro with VB script

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-office, vba

I am working on a project aimed at showing how to run a macro in Microsoft Office using an external vbscript file. I have tried severally and failed at it also found a couple of posts here, all leaned towards Excel than Office. Having difficulties getting those examples to work on Office.

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Excel - but the steps and procedures are identical in Word. I would search and replace Word for Excel but the code samples wouldn't make sense.

Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.

This applies (I don't have a medium9) xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

So first look up constants in vba's object browser. xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17

Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

```
Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.

Alt + T, M, R

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```